# Написать запрос по выборке sql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть одна таблица `monitoring` со столбцами ID клиента `ID`, последняя дата входа в приложение `Time`. Написал запрос по выводу таблицы в какое время был доступ клиентов к системе в виде: **Время - Количество входов - Айдишки клиентов**.

Запрос: `select Time, count(*) as Quantity, group_concat(ClientID) from monitoring group by Time`.

Как написать следующий запрос? Вывести таблицу в таком же виде, только теперь нужно по каждому времени, когда был доступ хотя бы 1-го клиента, вывести id всех клиентов, которые у которых по этому времени не было доступа.

UPD.

```
+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| Time                | Quantity    | ClientID       |                                                                                               
+---------------------+-------------+----------------+                                                                                                             
| 2018-06-14 15:51:03 |       3     | 311,240,528    |                                                                                                    
| 2018-06-14 15:51:20 |       3     | 314,312,519    |                                                                                                    
| 2019-01-14 06:00:07 |       1     | 359            |                                                                                                    
| 2019-08-21 14:30:04 |       1     | 269            |                                                                                                    
+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Это айдишки клиентов, у которых в данное время был доступ. А нужно вывести айди всех клиентов, у которых не было доступа именно в это время
Тоесть в данном случае:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| Time                | Quantity    | ClientID                    |                                                                                               
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+                                                                                                            
| 2018-06-14 15:51:03 |           5 | 269,359,314,312,519         |                                                                                                    
| 2018-06-14 15:51:20 |           5 | 311,240,528,359,269         |                                                                                                    
| 2019-01-14 06:00:07 |           7 | 311,240,528,314,312,519,269 |                                                                                                    
| 2019-08-21 14:30:04 |           7 | 311,240,528,314,312,519,359 |                                                                                                    
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Желательно, не учитывать день и время, а только год и месяц. Но уже как выйдет. Спасибо.

Comment: У таблицы `monitoring` всего два столбца? т.е., если у конкретного клиента в ней, например, три записи `ClientID | Time`, то последняя (третья) запись - это клиент в он-или-офф_лайне?

Comment: нет, 3й записи нет. нужно вывести айди клиентов, которые в данное время не заходили

Comment: тоесть нужно как-то пройти по каждому времени и вывести Время-Клиенты, клиентов, которые по этому времени не заходили

Comment: *"... вывести id всех клиентов, которые были оффлайн"* если в этой таблице клиенты и онлайн и офлайн, то по какому признаку их отличать, либо последние три слова в вопросе лишние.

Comment: прошу прощения, немного неправильно выразился, пофиксил

Comment: Есть возможность показать тестовые данные таблицы сток на 8-10 и желаемый результат ? т.е. ваш `create table monitoring (id ...` и данные туда `insert into monitoring (id, time) values (..., ...);`

Comment: поправил задание

Comment: @Alex поправил задание сверху